# Pros and Cons Alamofire Concurrency vs Regular or suggested method

Tags: swift, concurrency, closures, alamofire

Can some explain me the pros and cons about Alamofire Concurrency and Alamofire regular suggested method?
Concurrency way

```
func getDataConcurrency() async throws -> SomeModel {
    let dataTask = AF.request("/getData")
        .validate()
        .serializingDecodable(SomeModel.self)
    let response = await dataTask.response
    
    switch response.result {
    case .success(let model):
        return SomeModel
    case .failure(let err):
        throw err
    }
}
```

Regular, default or suggested method by Alamofire

```
func getDataRegularMethod(completion: @escaping (Result<SomeModel, AFError>) -> Void) {
    AF.request("/getData")
    .validate()
    .responseDecodable(of: SomeModel.self) { response in
        switch response.result {
        case .success(let someModel):
            completion(.success(someModel))
        case .failure:
            completion(.failure(.someAFError)
        }
    }
}
```

Understand and chose the best option

Comment: The first uses modern Swift concurrency. The second uses the old outdated completion handler approach. Read the [Concurrency](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/concurrency) chapter in the Swift book for more information.

Comment: Watch “Meet async/await” from WWDC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In terms of pros of Swift concurrency, in general:

- No completion handlers are needed (often making code easier to reason about);
- No `switch` of `Result` types are needed anymore; and
- It has more graceful support of cancelation.

In terms of cons:

- It requires apps targeting iOS 13 or macOS Catalina or later;
- It requires Swift 5.6 or later and Xcode 13.3.1 or later (but this is probably moot, because as of [April](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=jd9wcyov), “apps submitted to the App Store must be built with Xcode 14.1 or later” anyway);
- If you use Swift concurrency, you probably want the whole project to use Swift concurrency and retire the GCD pattern … it is not generally advised to mix asynchronous patterns within the same project; and
- If you are new to Swift concurrency, actors, `async`-`await`, `Sendable` types, etc., there is a bit of a learning curve.

The cons tend to be more constraints than actual disadvantages. Bottom line, if you *can* use `async`-`await`, you probably *should.* But feel free to do whatever you want, and just be consistent (whether that be traditional completion-handler patterns, Combine, or Swift concurrency). But Swift concurrency is the emerging standard, so if you choose to use the legacy completion-handler patterns, you probably would need a pretty compelling case to so.

Now, if you have already adopted `async`-`await` in your project and are simply wondering whether you should also adopt this pattern with Alamofire, too, the answer is, yes, you probably should. There is no downside and, as you will see below, it simplifies your code.

---

FWIW, your Swift concurrency example can be further simplified:

```swift
func getDataConcurrency(for url: URL) async throws -> SomeModel {
    try await AF.request(url)
        .validate()
        .serializingDecodable(SomeModel.self, automaticallyCancelling: true)
        .value
}
```

If the request succeeds, the value will be returned. If it fails, the error will be thrown. If you cancel the task, the requests will be automatically canceled. No completion handlers or `switch` statements are necessary.

---

In you are interested in more information about Swift concurrency and its advantages, see WWDC 2021 video [Meet async/await in Swift](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10132/), as well as the other videos on that page.

Comment: FWIW, I’ve opened issue [#3727](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/3727) on Alamofire suggesting that `automaticallyCancelling` really should default to `true`, and not require us to set this manually. I understand why they defaulted this to `false`, as support was flaky in Xcode 13.2, but I believe this issue has been resolved. Stay tuned.

Comment: in some cases the reasons that i added the switch case is because i want to grab the response.data that data contains the error validation from the API 
but in other scenario where i wont need that data i just throw the error 
and the way that you show me is more practical 
thanks for your quick response
I just wanted to make sure that chose the best option @rob

Comment: @CarlosAlvarado - The objection is not `switch`, per se. But `switch` on a `Result` (looking for `.success`/`.failure` cases) is almost always (with isolated exceptions) code smell in Swift concurrency. The purpose of `Result` enum type is to offer error handling in completion-handler code, and is an anachronism Swift concurrency codebase. Most of us would do `try await` on AF’s `value`, and then examine the various properties of `SomeModel` to see if there was some API-level condition that we want to detect and possibly `throw` an error. But `success`/`failure` switch is an anti-pattern.

Comment: But, hey, do whatever you want. My answer was based upon the code in the original question, where the `switch` just adds syntactic noise and offers no additional value. Maybe you’ve got some example where it is needed (though I confess to being skeptical … most `Result`-based async code I see on Stack Overflow is just devs falling into old, familiar patterns), but most of us have largely retired the `switch` on `Result` types in Swift concurrency.